# Run commands on failing build

Tags: f#-fake

Is there a way to implement a conceptual `finally` clause in a FAKE script, or to formulate it differently is there an alternative to `RunTargetOrDefault` that allows one to specify a `Target` that should be run when a build fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAKE provides a way to register a target that will run on failed build, via the `BuildFailureTarget` constructor.

```
BuildFailureTarget "ShootMyself" <| fun _ -> ShotgunHelper.Shoot (left foot)
```

See [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/specifictargets.html) for more info.